# sbt 1.1.1 ignores dependencies with classifiers for transitive dependencies

Tags: sbt

I built a library against multiple versions of another dependencies, using classifiers to separate them.

Now I want to reference this:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.mycompany" %% "mylib" % "x.y.z" classifier "otherlib-foo"
```

When I run `sbt compile` the classifier is partly ignored. The `mylib` is correctly loaded but it depends on another library with the classifier, and it only resolves its dependency without it.

What am I missing?

## Followup 1

I added:

```
transitiveClassifiers in Global := Seq(Artifact.SourceClassifier, "otherlib-foo")
```

but it didn't change anything

## Followup 2

When I change the classifier by changing my Git branch (There need to be some source adjustments for the dependent library) and republish it, Spark overwrites the pom.

Currently I stuck to putting the "classifier" into the version string (i.e. "x.y.z-otherlib-foo" as a workaround and using this one, but this can't be the way...

Comment: I solved this using Coursier to manage these assets. It follows transitive dependencies with classifiers.